# Average values of the waveform

Tags: wave-equation

What is the formula to find the average value of this waveform? What is the relation between the peak to peak value and average value of this waveform? Note that it's not an alternating wave. It's positive but changing wave.

[image]

Comment: Assuming the function is periodic, the average value over one period (and hence for the whole function) $\frac1T \int_0^T f(x)dx$, where $T$ is the length of the period and $f$ is a function describing your signal. In general there’s no relation between the peak to peak amplitude and the average, since a sine wave has zero average.